# EF Core ChangeTracker entities snapshot and reset to that snapshot

Tags: entity-framework-core, transactions, snapshot, change-tracking, retry-logic

Is it possible to take a snapshot of the current state of EF Core's `ChangeTracker` and then reset later to that snapshot if needed?
Let's say I want to make the following code into reality:

```
public async Task ExecuteTransactionAsync(DbContext context)
{
    var executionStrategy = new SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy(context);
    var retries = 0;
    var snapshot = null;

    await executionStrategy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
    {
        var txOptions = new TransactionOptions
        {
            IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted
        };
        using var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, txOptions, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled)

        if (retries > 0 && snapshot != null)
        {
            // This method in reality doesn't exist.
            context.ChangeTracker.ResetToSnapshot(snapshot);
        }
        // This method in reality doesn't exist.
        var snapshot = context.ChangeTracker.TakeSnapshot();

        retries += 1;
        
        // Let's imagine that we are doing an insert operation on the context.
        context.DoInsert();

        await context.SaveChangesAsync(false);

        // Let's imagine that we are doing an update operation on the context.
        context.DoUpdate();

        // Let's say this SaveChanges fails the first time and the transaction will retry.
        await context.SaveChangesAsync(false);

        transaction.Complete();
    }
}
```

**Why would this be useful?**
I have found it hard to work with `ChangeTracker` and retrying transactions. The transaction itself of course works fine, the changes will be rollbacked database side between retries. However, `ChangeTracker` doesn't seem to have a similar rollback functionality.
There is `SaveChanges(false)` option which is supposed to be used with transactions in order to preserve the state of `ChangeTracker` between retries. However, if I had an insert on the first run of the transaction, on the second run (first retry) another entity would be added to the `ChangeTracker` and then on successful `SaveChanges`, two entities would get inserted to database, but my expectation from the code was to have one entity inserted.

```
public async Task ExecuteTransactionAsync(DbContext context)
{
    var executionStrategy = new SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy(context);

    await executionStrategy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
    {
        var txOptions = new TransactionOptions
        {
            IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted
        };
        using var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, txOptions, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled)

        // On the first retry, the ChangeTracker will already have a new entity added.
        // DoInsert will add another one and now I will have two new entities
        // when my expectation was just one.
        context.DoInsert();

        await context.SaveChangesAsync(false);

        context.DoUpdate();

        // Let's say this SaveChanges fails the first time and the transaction will retry.
        await context.SaveChangesAsync(false);

        transaction.Complete();
    }
}
```

A similar problem would occur when updating an entity with `+=` or `-=` operators. If, for example, an entity had `Price = 10` and `.DoUpdate` would do `Price -= 2` - after the first retry (so after the code wrapped in the transaction would run twice) I would have `Price = 6` because it was subtracted twice, when my expectation at the end of the transaction was to have `Price = 8`.

So it got me thinking that a total reset to some `ChangeTracker` state in some point of time would be extremely useful.